# Prove the pseudo k-regular bipartite graphs has a perfect matching

Tags: graph-theory, bipartite-graphs, matching-theory, graph-connectivity

Suppose we have a bipartite graph $G=(X∪Y,E)$. It has the following properties：

- $|X| = |Y|$
- Maximum degree of vertices is $k$

I want to extend $G$ to a $k$-regular bipartite graph. So I write a loop to **add edges to vertices whose degree is less than $k$**. The loop only **ends** when there are **no more edges to add**. The filled bipartite graph obtained by the above loop may not be a $k$-regular bipartite graph but a bipartite graph **with most vertices of degree $k$ and some vertices of degree less than $k$**, and it is **no longer possible to increase the degree** of these vertices by adding edges.

So I call these filled bipartite graphs as the **pseudo $k$-regular bipartite graphs**. My question is that how to prove that the pseudo $k$-regular bipartite graph **also has the perfect matching**.

I found that this conclusion should be correct when I randomly disrupted the bipartite graph 10000 times by simulation, but I don't know how to prove it theoretically.

Comment: The usual tool for this sort of problem is Hall's Marriage Theorem. I am not sure, but I suspect if this is true that's the thing to use.

Comment: I know Hall's Marriage Theorem, and also have learned how to prove that the k-regular bipartite graph has a perfect match, but my knowledge of graph theory is weak, I did not find the answer to this question on the Internet, and I have been thinking about it for a long time, but I have not found a solution.

Comment: @zhenwei zhai, could you please clarify the definition of a pseudo k-regular bipartite graph?

Comment: I'm sorry the previous description was not clear，I have update the question.

Answer (score 1):

> THM 1: A $k$-pseudoregular bipartite graph always has a perfect matching.

We now show this. Let $H'$ be a pseudo $k$-regular graph to start with.

**TLDR:** First we observe the following: There is a $k$-regular multigraph $H$, where there is an edge between 2 vertices in $H$ only if there is an edge between 2 vertices in $H'$. Then we use the fact that $H$ is a $k$-regular bipartite multigraph to observe via combinatorial reasoning that $|S| \le |N_H(S)|$ for all subsets $S$ of $X$. Then we see that $N_H(S) =N_{H'}(S)$, and so of course this implies that $|S| \le |N_{H'}(S)|$ as well. Then we see by Hall's there is a matching on $H'$ that saturates $X$ and so as $|X|=|Y|$ we also see that there is a perfect matching on $H'$.

---

**To elaborate** we first make the following observation:

> Claim 0: You can always add edges to $H'$ until you get a $k$-regular bipartite **multigraph** $H$ that satisfies the following: if there is at an edge between $x$ and $y$ in $H$, then there is an edge between $x$ and $y$ in $H'$.

Indeed, let $y \in Y$ be a vertex of degree still less than $k$. Then there is a vertex $x \in X$ of degree less than $k$ [make sure you see why this is]. And furthermore, $xy$ form an edge in $H'$ otherwise $x$ and $y$ would have been connected in $H'$ already by the construction of $H'$. Add an edge between them.

We now note the following:

> Claim 1: For each $S \subset X$, the inequality $|S| \le |N_H(S)|$ holds.

Indeed, we now present some notation. For each vertex $y' \in Y$ and any subset $U$ of $X$, let $d_U(y')$ be the number of edges in $H$ [the $k$-regular multigraph] of the form $y'x; x \in U$. Likewise, for each vertex $x' \in X$ and any subset $V$ of $Y$,  let $d_V(x')$ be the number of edges in $H$ [the $k$-regular multigraph] of the form $yx'; y \in V$.

Then for each subset $S$ of $X$, note that on the one hand, $d_{N(H)}(x) = k$ for each $x \in S$. So the following equation holds:
$$\sum_{x \in S} d_{N(H)}(x) = \sum_
{x \in S} k \ = \ k|S|.$$
However, $d_S(y) \le k$ for each $y \in N_H(S)$. So the following equation holds:
$$\sum_{y \in N_H(S)} d_{S}(x) \le k |N_{H}(S)|.$$
However, [make sure you see that] the following also holds:
$$\sum_{x \in S} d_{N(H)}(x) = \sum_{y \in N_H(S)} d_{S}(x).$$
[Indeed, both sides of the above count exactly the number of edges with one endpoint in $S$ and the other in $N_H(S)$.] So putting all these together gives
$$k|S| \le k|N_H(S)|,$$
which, dividing both sides of the above by $k$, yields Claim 1. $\surd$

> Claim 2: For each $S \subset X$, the inequality $|S| \le |N_{H'}(S)|$ holds.

Claim 2 follows from Claim 1, and the fact that there is an edge between $x$ and $y$ in $H$ only if there is an edge between $x$ and $y$ in $H'$. $\surd$

Finish the proof of THM 1 by Hall's Matching Thm, and noting that any matching that saturates $X$, must also saturate $Y$. $\surd$

Comment: I don't quite understand Claim 0. In my opinion, if the degree of x in H′ is less than k, then the number of NH′(x)  is less than the number of NH(x). So there is a situation where there is a edge in H and no connection in H', and claim 0 is not valid in my opinion. Could you please give me an example to explain claim 0 again?

Comment: Sure. If there is a vertex $x\in X$ that has degree less than $k$ in $H'$, then one can use combinatorial reasoning to show that there is a vertex $y \in Y$ with degree less than $k$ in $H'$. By the fact that $H'$ is $k$-pseudoregular, $x$ and $y$ must form an edge in $H'$, otherwise the edge $xy$ could be added into $H'$.

Comment: So in the multigraph  $H$ there is more than 1 edge between $x$ and $y$, whereas in $H'$ there is exactly 1 edge between $x$ and $y$. So $y$ is still in $N_{H'}(x)$ as it is in $N_H(x)$, it is that there is more than 1 edge between $x$ and $y$ in $H$, whereas there is exactly 1 edge between $x$ and $y$ in $H'$, that gives $d_H(x)>d_{H'}(x)$.